# Pass by reference to base class constructor from derived class constructor

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I would like to include a reference of a struct, `Coord`, within a class, `Base`, from the initializer list of derived class, `Derived`. When I pass the instance of `Coord` to the `Derived` class constructor, a new instance of `Coord` is created - or at least I assume this is what is happening because I cannot update my `coord` object from the derived class.

Am I breaking some sort of rule by passing a reference in this way? Or just doing it incorrectly?

See Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Coord{
  int x = 1;
  int y = 1;
  void printCoord(){
    std::cout << "X: " << x << " Y: " << y << std::endl;
  }
};

class Base{

  public:
  Coord myCoord;
  Base(Coord &coord): myCoord(coord){} // How do I modify this line so Base gets a copy of myCoord?
  virtual void updateCoord(int x, int y){};

};

class Derived : public Base {

  public:
  Derived(Coord &coord): Base(coord){} // Or possibly this line?
  virtual void updateCoord(int x, int y){ 
    myCoord.x = x;
    myCoord.y = y;  
    std::cout << "Updated to:" << std::endl;
    myCoord.printCoord();
  }
};

int main(){
  Coord myCoord;
  Base *baseptr;
  Derived d(myCoord);
  baseptr = &d;

  std::cout << "Before update:" << std::endl;
  myCoord.printCoord();
  baseptr->updateCoord(2,2);
  std::cout << "After update:" << std::endl;
  myCoord.printCoord();

  return 0;
}
```

I expect to get the following output:

```
Before update:
X: 1 Y: 1
Updated to:
X: 2 Y: 2
After update:
X: 2 Y: 2
```

But instead get:

```
Before update:
X: 1 Y: 1
Updated to:
X: 2 Y: 2
After update:
X: 1 Y: 1
```

Comment: _"I would like to include a reference of a struct"_ `Coord myCoord;` is an owned `Coord` value. If you want to hold a reference to a `Coord`, that should be `Coord& myCoord;`.

Comment: FYI, for a [mre], you should be sure to remove any code that isn't required to reproduce the issue. In this case, the `Base`-`Derived` class hierarchy actually isn't needed. Only an assignment from a `Coord&` to a `Coord` is.

Comment: "How do I modify ... so base gets a copy". No you don't want a copy, you want a reference.

Comment: @Brian61354270 If you want to hold a reference to a Coord, *think again, and just don't*. Here, FTFY.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I was obviously holding on to the idea that I was not initializing my base class correctly- and could not see that I incorrectly declared `Coord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration of `myCoord` in Base to be a reference:

```
class Base{

  public:
  Coord& myCoord;  // reference declaration
  Base(Coord &coord): myCoord(coord){} // How do I modify this line so Base gets a copy of myCoord?
  virtual void updateCoord(int x, int y){};

};
```

Then myCoord will be the same reference as your instance of Coord in `main`.